# Is there any API to search a document in Quip with given word

Tags: quip, liveapps

Given a folder, looking for Quip API (Enterprise version) where any document can be searched with a given Subject line or Document Title or File name

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of documents and sub-folders in any quip folder via the api's get_folders.  You can pass it one or more ids.  You can then search these using regex for example. https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#folders-get

I also recommend checking out the python SDK on github 
 https://github.com/quip/quip-api

Here is an example python function to grab favorited folders and documents(Note this only grabs the top level and does not recurse down)

```
 def getFavs(self):
    folders = []
    threads = []
    children = self.client.get_folder(self.client.get_authenticated_user()["starred_folder_id"])["children"]
    for child in children:
        if "folder_id" in child.keys():
            folder = self.client.get_folder(child["folder_id"])
            folders.append(str(folder["folder"]["id"]))
        if "thread_id" in child.keys():
            thread = self.client.get_thread(child["thread_id"])["thread"]
            threads.append(str(thread["id"]))
    return folders,threads
```